# Get list of files from R instance

Tags: java, r

I do NOT have much information about R.

I have an R user credentials.

Need to write a java program which displays the list of files/directories available on the server on which R is installed (using R user credentials only). User would navigate through the directories, and would select one file. My java code would fetch the file.

If the R instance has R serve package installed, my java code can use [REngine.jar](https://github.com/s-u/REngine) and use list.files and list.dirs commands in [eval()](https://github.com/s-u/REngine/blob/master/Rserve/RConnection.java#L255):

Will need to manipulate the output of this two commands to generate a single list. A wrapper java program can be written using these two commands so that user will be able to navigate through the files/directories.

It is easy for linux server. There is one tree of files - linux file-system.

It gets tricky when R instance is on a windows machine. Need to get the list of drives on the machine:

```
> system("cmd.exe /c wmic logicaldisk get name", intern = F)
Name  
C:    
D:
```

Need to check the OS as following:

```
> .Platform$OS.type
[1] "windows"
```

So, the flow differs based on underlying OS - windows or unix-like.

1. Is there a way to write my java program which is NOT dependent on the underlying OS of the server on which R is installed?
2. Are there any REST APIs for listing files/directories or any R pacakages which would help me achieve the same?
3. Can I remove the file business at all? Is there a way to just get a particular "report"? (Not sure, if the "report" term exists for R). Run a particular script on R, and just give me the output of the script in response of some API. Are there such APIs?

Comment: It’s completely unclear what you mean by “the list of files/directories available on R”. More generally, it’s completely unclear what you want and what the problem is.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I understood my use-case well, and corrected the question. :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, if the question is understandable now, I would request you to remove the downvote. :)

Comment: I never downvoted the question.

Comment: Thanks, @KonradRudolph.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Microsoft R Server on the Server Machine and the Expose R scripts to a RestAPI via the operationalization feature, please see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/operationalize/admin-get-started

For more information on Microsoft R Server, please see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/rserver